# Set button in collectionViewCell is Pressed and vice-versa

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

**I have a collectionView and a cell in it with my categories.**
[image: here they are]

**I need to set Pressed and unpressed. two state. My cell consist just a label in it. Without buttons. here is some my code. I think its very easy to do.**

```
class CategoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, NibLoadable {

enum state {
case pressed
case unpressed
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    Decorator.decorate(self)
    addTargets()
}

func setText(text: String) {
    label.text = text
}

func setFont(font: UIFont) {
    label.font = font
}

func setFontColor(color: UIColor) {
    label.textColor = color
}

func setColor(backgroundColor: UIColor, borderColor: CGColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
}

private func addTargets() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func tapped() {

}
```

}

**as u can see I made function to change color on cell.**

**here is my methods in VC**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let category = categories[indexPath.item]

    if category.id == "userId" {

      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:CategoryCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = category.name
        return cell
    } else if category.id == "UniqueID" {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addNewCategory))
        cell.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.label.text = "+ add"
        cell.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        cell.setColor(backgroundColor: .white, borderColor: monPurple.cgColor, borderWidth: 1.0)
        cell.setFontColor(color: .purple)
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell.init()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets (top: 10, left: 16, bottom: 10, right: 16)
}
```

**any thoughts my friends?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using tap gesture, when you can use collection view delegate for that use didSelectItem delegate method.

I'm assuming you don't know that so I'm attaching an example for this

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)
```

here in this function, you can get the tap of collectionviewcell itself.

now to your problem, you need to maintain a model class which will help you to persist your data.

Example -

```
struct CategoryModel {

    var categoryName : String
    var isCategorySelected : Bool //or you can use your enum here
}
```

in your vc intialize this model array im assuming this

```
var dataModels : [CategoryModel] // you fill it
```

now in you cellforItemAt

manange the selected and unselected state of the your cell

for example

```
if dataModels[indexPath.item].isCategorySelected == true {
    //manage selected cell state
}else  {
    //manage unselected cell state

}


func collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath) {

    dataModels[indexPath.item].isCategorySelected = !dataModels[indexPath.item].isCategorySelected //change your model data here according to the tap
    // now reload your cell here for that specific indexpath

}
```